# Undesired session creation

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, session-cookies

I have two JSP pages: `Login.jsp` and `Main.jsp`.

For the url pattern `/` I have a servlet which does this:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session == null) {
    response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");
} else {
    response.sendRedirect("Home.jsp");
}
```

The two JSP pages are empty as of now.

When I browse `localhost:8080/appname/` in my browser, it routes to `Login.jsp` as expected. But when I try to browse it for the second time, it routes to `Home.jsp`.

When I try to debug, `session` is not null and I could find a cookie with `JSESSIONID` in my chrome browser.

I don't do `getSession()` anywhere else.

Can anyone explain me what is going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSP creates a session by default. If you don't want a session then add

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not only jsp, any request on server will start a session. So what is happening is first time you are not getting any session but next time you are getting the session which was created in the earlier request.

What you can do is:
a) Set some attribute of session and instead of checking session check for the attribute which will be set only once the user is logged in.
b) you can try invalidating session each time. Also make sure even when you authenticating user invalidate the session and then generate session and then set the attribute of session.

Comment: >>any request on server will start a session

Comment: A Servlet does not create a session unless you write code to do so.

Comment: hmm...my bad...thanks for the information. I just confused two things. I confused it with session fixation concepts, and now when I realize back, I come to know that it is not because when we hit the server, but when either we call getSession() or getSession(true) or we open a jsp, the session starts. Apologies and thanks for the same.